# Cancel export process in Primefaces datatable at preProcessor stage

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a simple datatable which I'm exporting and I need to decide at preProcessor stage if the export should continue depending on whether there is another export currently running or not (it's a 30000 records table and two concurrent exports just kills the CPU). Is it possible in any way? The best I achieved is to throw an exception at the preProcessor method; this will break the client's page but at least won't kill my server's CPU. The decision must be taken at the moment the export begins, because depending on a lock's state the export process should continue or just throw a message sugesting to "try again later".
Thanks.

Comment: Why not create / use an exception handler which converts the exception to a Faces message? For example http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FacesMessageExceptionHandler

Comment: You can use PrimeFaces MonitorDownload (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml), and show an ajaxStatus dialog with modal while one export process is being made (this way user won't be able to click anything on your screen including expot button again until the download is finished), or you can dissable the export button onclick and oncomplete enable it ;)

Comment: Also what type of export are you doing CSV, XLSX, PDF?  I wonder what is killing the CPU because CSV will be fast if it is XLSX have you tried XLSXSTREAM instead?

Comment: I've tried both MonitorDownload and ajaxExceptionHandler without success, but I guess I'm doing something wrong. Now that you validate those options I'll try a bit harder in order to make it work.

Comment: @imnotthatrobot yes, you need to define a start and stop function (javascript) so for example in start function you can call dialog.show(); and in stop function just call dialog.hide(); this is how I use it on my project: onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startDialog,stopDialog);" I have PrimeFaces 7.0 btw

Comment: @Melloware It's an XLSX. XLSXSTREAM throws "Could Not Auto-size Column in p:dataExporter" exception and as far as I know it requires PF 6.3+ in order to work. This would be a very interesting option but I'm conditioned to not change the PF version.

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast maybe it's a PF version thing... I'm pretty sure I sticked to the documentation when I tried this one... anyway, I'll give it another chance and report it later here. thks

Comment: Yes it should work even with PF 3.4 but in this version (3.4) you gotta use it Primefaces.monitorDownload(startDialog,stopDialog); notice that Primefaces is in lower case, and in PF 7.0 its PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startDialog,stopDialog); hope it helps

Comment: Why not make it a 'two step export' and prevent the export to start at all when another is running?

Comment: @Kukeltje could you extend please?

Comment: @Kukeltje no need for a workaround lol, there is PrimeFaces monitordownload :p

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast it didn't work with monitorDownload. It works most of the times, but it fails when you use it with a dataExporter. In fact, the onclick event itselft doesn't trigger at all inside the dataExporter's commandLink.

Comment: @imnotthatrobot hmm haven't use it with commandLink bro, try commandButton

Comment: @imnotthatrobot and if you cant use commandButton then make it hidden, and use the onclick attribute of commandlink to trigger a click on the hiddenButton

Comment: You need a better server if an export of a table that small is killing the server. Alternatively you could set a flag in an application scoped bean when using a preprocessor method and clear it when the document is completed in a postprocessor method.